# Is there a nice way to add unique items from inner collections using LINQ method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

### Code

```cs
List<Element> elements = GetElementsList();

ISet<string> usedInnerElements = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (Element element in elements)
{
    foreach (InnerElement innerElement in element.InnerCollection.InnerElements)
    {
        usedInnerElements.Add(innerElement.SomeValue);
    }
}

class Element 
{
    public InnerCollection InnerCollection { get; set; }
}

class InnerCollection
{
    public List<InnerElement> InnerElements { get; set; }
}

class InnerElement
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

This code scan inner collections of some other collection and save only unique values.

### Question

Is there any way to present it in more fluent way using LINQ method syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we can assume that none of the values can be `null` then the simplest solution I can think of:

```
ISet<string> usedInnerElements = elements
    .SelectMany(coll => coll.InnerCollection.InnerElements
        .Select(elem => elem.SomeValue))
    .Distinct()
    .ToHashSet();
```

1. With `SelectMany` we are reducing the dimensions (flattening) from `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` to `IEnumerable<string>`
2. With `Select` we retrieve the `string` value from its wrapper class
3. With `Distinct` we are making sure that we are getting rid of from all duplicates
4. With `ToHashSet` we simply convert the `IEnumerable<string>` to `ISet<string>`

Test Input:

```
var elements = new List<Element>
{
    new Element
    {
        InnerCollection = new InnerCollection
        {
            InnerElements = new List<InnerElement>
            {
                new InnerElement { SomeValue = "A" },
                new InnerElement { SomeValue = "C" },
                new InnerElement { SomeValue = "E" },
            }
        }
    },
    new Element
    {
        InnerCollection = new InnerCollection
        {
            InnerElements = new List<InnerElement>
            {
                new InnerElement { SomeValue = "E" },
                new InnerElement { SomeValue = "A" },
                new InnerElement { SomeValue = "B" },
            }
        }
    }
};
...
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", usedInnerElements));
```

Test output:

```
A,C,E,B
```

---

If you have to deal with null values then the query might look like this:

```
ISet<string> usedInnerElements = elements
    .Where(coll => coll != null
        && coll.InnerCollection != null
        && coll.InnerCollection.InnerElements != null)
    .SelectMany(coll => coll.InnerCollection.InnerElements
        .Where(elem => elem != null)
        .Select(elem => elem.SomeValue))
    .Distinct()
    .ToHashSet();
```

Test input

```
var elements = new List<Element>
{
    null,
    new Element
    {
        InnerCollection = null
    },
    new Element
    {
        InnerCollection = new InnerCollection
        {
            InnerElements = null
        }
    },
    new Element
    {
        InnerCollection = new InnerCollection
        {
            InnerElements = new List<InnerElement>
            {
                new InnerElement { SomeValue = "E" },
                new InnerElement(),
                null
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Test output

```
E,
```